# Python: How to add information to a dictionary using a class, then print key and values of added dictionary entry

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object-oriented-database

### I'm working on the following assignment and am new to using classes to create/store objects:

> Employee Management System: This exercise assumes you have created the Employee class for Programming Exercise 4. Create a program that stores Employee objects in a dictionary. Use the employee ID number as the key. The program should present a menu that lets the user perform the following actions: Look up an employee in the dictionary, Add a new employee to the dictionary, Change an existing employee’s name, department, and job title in the dictionary, Delete an employee from the dictionary, Quit the program.
> When the program ends, it should pickle the dictionary and save it to a file. Each time the
> program starts, it should try to load the pickled dictionary from the file. If the file does not exist,
> the program should start with an empty dictionary.

Everything went smoothly until I ran the program and was unable to print the information properly when using the employee lookup function. When running the code:

```py
if ID in dictionary.keys():
    print(ID, ': ', dictionary[ID])
```

The output is:

```py
1 :  <Employee.Employee object at 0x03520340>
```

I've attached an image of the program running when I add an employee and then try to look it up afterwards. I think there may be a problem with how I saved the data in the first place in the add function, or an issue in accessing the data in the lookup function.
Is there a different way to print the contents of the dictionary for the specified ID? Have I stored the object properties improperly in the first place?

---

### For reference, here is the rest of my code:

Employee.py (employee class in its own file):

```py
class Employee:
    # Initialize Employee object
    def __init__(self, ID, name, department, job):
        self.__name = name
        self.__ID = ID
        self.__department = department
        self.__job = job

    # Set each object
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_ID(self, ID):
        self.__ID = ID

    def set_dept(self, department):
        self.__department = department

    def set_job(self, job):
        self.__job = job

    # Get each object
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_ID(self):
        return self.__ID

    def get_department(self):
        return self.__department

    def get_job(self):
        return self.__job


    def print(self):
        print("Name: " + self.__name + \
               ", ID Number: " + self.__ID + \
               ", Department: " + self.__department + \
               ", Job Title: " + self.__job)
```

EmployeeManagementSystem.py:

```py
# Import necessary libraries
import pickle
import Employee
    
    
# STEP 1 = DEFINE FUNCTIONS FOR EACH CHOICE

# Lookup an employee
def lookup(dictionary):
    # Look up the ID number if it is in the dictionary
    ID = int(input('Enter the employee ID number: '))
    if ID in dictionary.keys():
        print(ID, ': ', dictionary[ID])
        print(dictionary.get(ID)) 
    else:
    print("That ID number was not found.")

    # Offer the user the menu of choices again from main()
    proceed = True
    return proceed


# Add an employee
def add(dictionary):
    # Add a new employee
    ID = int(input('Enter the employee ID number: '))
    name = input('Enter the name of the employee: ')
    dept = input('Enter the employee department: ')
    job = input('Enter the employee job title: ')
  
    entry = Employee.Employee(ID, name, dept, job)
    dictionary[ID] = entry
    print('Employee added succesfully')
   
    # Offer the user the menu of choices again from main()
    proceed = True
    return proceed
    
    
# Change an employee    
def change(dictionary):
    # If user-entered ID is in dictionary, allow them to change the info
    ID = input('Enter the employee ID you would like to change: ')
    if ID in dictionary.keys():
        name = input('Enter new employee name: ')
        newId = input('Enter new employee ID: ')
        dept = input('Enter new employee department: ')
        job = input('Enter new employee job title: ')
        entry = Employee.Employee(newID, name, dept, job)
        dictionary[ID] = entry
        print('Employee changed successfully.')
    else:
        print('That employee ID was not found.')
    
    # Offer the user the menu of choices again from main()
    proceed = True
    return proceed
    
    
# Delete an employee
def delete(dictionary):
    # If user-entered ID is in dictionary, delete the entry
    ID = input('Enter the employee ID you would like to remove: ')
    if ID in dictionary.keys():
        del dictionary[ID]
        print('Employee removed successfully')
    else:
        print('That employe ID was not found.')
 
    # Offer the user the menu of choices again from main()
    proceed = True
    return proceed
    
    
# Save the dictionary and quit the program
def save_quit(dictionary):
    # Pickle the dictionary and save to a file
    output_file = open('employee_data.dat','wb')
    pickle.dump(dictionary,output_file)
    output_file.close
    
        
    # End the while loop in main() so program quits
    proceed = False
    return proceed
```

```
# STEP 2 - Main Function
def main():

    # Try to open the existing dictionary file
    try:
        input_file = open('employee_data.dat','rb')
        employee_dictionary = pickle.load(input_file)
        input_file.close()

    # If no such file exists, create a new dictionary
    except:
        employee_dictionary = {}


    # While loop to continue until user chooses to quit
    proceed = True
    while proceed:

        # Display user's option menu and ask for a choice
        print('\n Employee Management System\n')
        print('\t1. Lookup an employee')
        print('\t2. Add a new employee')
        print('\t3. Change an existing employee')
        print('\t4. Delete an existing employee')
        print('\t5. Save and Quit\n')

        option_choice = int(input('Enter an option to continue: '))

        # Map each choice to the functions below using a dictionary
        options = {1:lookup, 2:add, 3:change, 4:delete, 5:save_quit,}
        proceed = options[option_choice](employee_dictionary)



# STEP 3 - CALL MAIN
# Call the main function
main()
```

Comment: You have to add a `__str__()` method to employee to tell python how to print it. Python has no idea how to print custom classes.

Comment: I changed the print method I had before to __str__() with a return statement, but now I get a 'Type Error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str'. Do I need to convert the employee ID to a string for it to be printed? Not sure how to do this within a class.

Comment: Yes, you can use `str(x)` to turn x into a string.

Comment: Fixed the str part, but when I print anything from the dictionary it still shows <Employee.Employee object at 0x03484D90> instead of the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def lookup(dictionary):
    # Look up the ID number if it is in the dictionary
    ID = int(input('Enter the employee ID number: '))
    if ID in dictionary.keys():
        x=dictionary.get(ID)
        x.print()

    else:
        print("That ID number was not found.")

    # Offer the user the menu of choices again from main()
    proceed = True
    return proceed
```

Since you already have a function for print call that
and there is an error in the print function to fix that change the 'self.__id' to 'str(self.__ID)'

```
    def print(self):
        print("Name: " + self.__name + \
               ", ID Number: " + str(self.__ID) + \
               ", Department: " + self.__department + \
               ", Job Title: " + self.__job)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `print` method in your `Employee` class to `__str__` like so:

```
class Employee:
    # Initialize Employee object
    def __init__(self, ID, name, department, job):
        self.__name = name
        self.__ID = ID
        self.__department = department
        self.__job = job

    # Set each object
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_ID(self, ID):
        self.__ID = ID

    def set_dept(self, department):
        self.__department = department

    def set_job(self, job):
        self.__job = job

    # Get each object
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_ID(self):
        return self.__ID

    def get_department(self):
        return self.__department

    def get_job(self):
        return self.__job

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"Name: {self.__name}, ID Number: {self.__ID}, "
                f"Department: {self.__department}, Job Title: {self.__job}")
```

And also fix some minor typos in your `EmployeeManagementSystem.py` file:

```
# Import necessary libraries
import pickle
import Employee


def get_int_input(prompt):
    num = -1
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input(prompt))
            break
        except:
            print("Error: Enter an integer, try again...")
    return num


# Lookup an employee
def lookup(dictionary):
    # Look up the ID number if it is in the dictionary
    employee_id = get_int_input('Enter the employee ID number: ')
    if employee_id in dictionary:
        # print('employee_id', ': ', dictionary[employee_id])
        print(dictionary.get(employee_id))
    else:
        print("That ID number was not found.")

    # Offer the user the menu of choices again from main()
    proceed = True
    return proceed


# Add an employee
def add(dictionary):
    # Add a new employee
    empyloyee_id = get_int_input('Enter the employee ID number: ')
    name = input('Enter the name of the employee: ')
    dept = input('Enter the employee department: ')
    job = input('Enter the employee job title: ')

    entry = Employee.Employee(empyloyee_id, name, dept, job)
    dictionary[empyloyee_id] = entry
    print('Employee added succesfully')

    # Offer the user the menu of choices again from main()
    proceed = True
    return proceed


# Change an employee
def change(dictionary):
    # If user-entered ID is in dictionary, allow them to change the info
    employee_id = get_int_input(
        'Enter the employee ID you would like to change: ')
    if employee_id in dictionary.keys():
        name = input('Enter new employee name: ')
        dept = input('Enter new employee department: ')
        job = input('Enter new employee job title: ')
        entry = Employee.Employee(employee_id, name, dept, job)
        dictionary[employee_id] = entry
        print('Employee changed successfully.')
    else:
        print('That employee ID was not found.')

    # Offer the user the menu of choices again from main()
    proceed = True
    return proceed


# Delete an employee
def delete(dictionary):
    # If user-entered ID is in dictionary, delete the entry
    employee_id = get_int_input(
        'Enter the employee ID you would like to remove: ')
    if employee_id in dictionary.keys():
        del dictionary[employee_id]
        print('Employee removed successfully')
    else:
        print('That employee ID was not found.')

    # Offer the user the menu of choices again from main()
    proceed = True
    return proceed


# Save the dictionary and quit the program
def save_quit(dictionary):
    # Pickle the dictionary and save to a file
    output_file = open('employee_data.dat', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(dictionary, output_file)
    output_file.close

    # End the while loop in main() so program quits
    proceed = False
    return proceed


# STEP 2 - Main Function
def main():
    # Try to open the existing dictionary file
    try:
        input_file = open('employee_data.dat', 'rb')
        employee_dictionary = pickle.load(input_file)
        input_file.close()

    # If no such file exists, create a new dictionary
    except:
        employee_dictionary = {}

    # While loop to continue until user chooses to quit
    proceed = True
    while proceed:

        # Display user's option menu and ask for a choice
        print('\n Employee Management System\n')
        print('\t1. Lookup an employee')
        print('\t2. Add a new employee')
        print('\t3. Change an existing employee')
        print('\t4. Delete an existing employee')
        print('\t5. Save and Quit\n')

        option_choice = get_int_input('Enter an option to continue: ')

        # Map each choice to the functions below using a dictionary
        options = {
            1: lookup,
            2: add,
            3: change,
            4: delete,
            5: save_quit,
        }
        proceed = options[option_choice](employee_dictionary)


# STEP 3 - CALL MAIN
# Call the main function
main()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
 Employee Management System

    1. Lookup an employee
    2. Add a new employee
    3. Change an existing employee
    4. Delete an existing employee
    5. Save and Quit

Enter an option to continue: 2
Enter the employee ID number: 123
Enter the name of the employee: asd
Enter the employee department: asd
Enter the employee job title: asd
Employee added succesfully

 Employee Management System

    1. Lookup an employee
    2. Add a new employee
    3. Change an existing employee
    4. Delete an existing employee
    5. Save and Quit

Enter an option to continue: 1
Enter the employee ID number: 123
Name: asd, ID Number: 123, Department: asd, Job Title: asd

 Employee Management System

    1. Lookup an employee
    2. Add a new employee
    3. Change an existing employee
    4. Delete an existing employee
    5. Save and Quit

Enter an option to continue: 3
Enter the employee ID you would like to change: asd
Error: Enter an integer, try again...
Enter the employee ID you would like to change: 123
Enter new employee name: zxc
Enter new employee department: zxc
Enter new employee job title: zxc
Employee changed successfully.

 Employee Management System

    1. Lookup an employee
    2. Add a new employee
    3. Change an existing employee
    4. Delete an existing employee
    5. Save and Quit

Enter an option to continue: 1
Enter the employee ID number: 123
Name: zxc, ID Number: 123, Department: zxc, Job Title: zxc

 Employee Management System

    1. Lookup an employee
    2. Add a new employee
    3. Change an existing employee
    4. Delete an existing employee
    5. Save and Quit

Enter an option to continue: 4
Enter the employee ID you would like to remove: 123
Employee removed successfully

 Employee Management System

    1. Lookup an employee
    2. Add a new employee
    3. Change an existing employee
    4. Delete an existing employee
    5. Save and Quit

Enter an option to continue: 1
Enter the employee ID number: 123
That ID number was not found.

 Employee Management System

    1. Lookup an employee
    2. Add a new employee
    3. Change an existing employee
    4. Delete an existing employee
    5. Save and Quit

Enter an option to continue: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I am tring to implement the switch case using dict but the function unable to call.so like the below code if the select 1 how addEmployee() method will be call.

```
  employee_dictionary = {}       
  while proceed:

       print('\n Employee Management System\n')
       print('\t1. Add a new employee')
       print('\t2. Delete an existing employee')
       print('\t3. Save and Quit\n')
       option_choice = int(input('Enter an option to continue: '))

       # Map each choice to the functions below using a dictionary
       options = {
           1:"addEmployeeInDict",
           2:"DeleteEmployee",
           3:"Exit"
       }
       proceed = options[option_choice](employee_dictionary)
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32014214)